# How to remove leading whitespace from first line of text files using batch file in Windows?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I've got about 700 .tcx files (old GPS running data if you're interested...).

The first line is:

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

That's 10 spaces at the start, which is preventing me from importing this data to Garmin Connect (I got a new Garmin watch).

So, I need to remove this whitespace from the front of this first line of 700 files. I'm trying to automate this process with a batch file (though given how long I've spent trying to do this, it would've been quicker to do it by hand...)

So far I've got:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /F "tokens=1" %%A in (C:\[path]\[filename].tcx) do (
    set line=%%A
    echo !line:~1! >> C:\[path]\[filename].tcx
)
endlocal
```

Where [path] is the path to where the files are currently stored, and filename is the file I'm testing on. Once I've got it working I will replace [filename[ with *

Unfortunately what I've got isn't quite working at the moment:

Firstly, it is going through the whole file, not just the first line.
Secondly, on each line, it is not just deleting the leading whitespace, it is deleting everything upto and including the first character (which is a "<") and then also deleting everything after the next space that is comes across.

I know my attempt is kind of pathetic, but I'm hoping to learn!

Comment: I  would wager that every single one of those files have the exact same first line. If so then you could simply replace the first line in each file with ```<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>```. Clearly however, as those files are supposed to be Unicode, whichever way you do it, you should use a language which natively uses UTF-8, like the built-in PowerShell.

Comment: This can be done with powershell, which is the right thing to do, as a one liner.

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
rem The following settings for the directories are names
rem that I use for testing and deliberately includes spaces to make sure
rem that the process works using such names. These will need to be changed to suit your situation.

SET "sourcedir=u:\your files"
SET "destdir=u:\your results"

FOR %%e IN ("%sourcedir%\*.tcx") DO (
 SET "first=y"
 (
  FOR /f "usebackqtokens=*" %%y IN ("%%e") DO IF DEFINED first SET "first="&ECHO %%y
  FOR /f "usebackqskip=1delims=" %%y IN ("%%e") DO ECHO %%y
 )>"%destdir%\%%~nxe"
)

GOTO :EOF
```

**Always verify against a test directory before applying to real data.**

Note that if the filename does not contain separators like spaces, then both `usebackq` and the quotes around `%filename1%` can be  omitted.

This should accomplish the task. It simply reads the first line from each file, removing leading spaces (one of the default `delims`) and sends it to the output, resetting the `first` flag to prevent regurgitation of the remaining data.

Next step is to reproduce all but the first line.

All gathered together by enclosing the two `for`s in parentheses and redirecting.

Note that the source and destination directories must be different.

Comment: THANK YOU! Yes, this has worked for me. 

Thank you also for the very helpful comments about how this works - I'm still bit bit clueless about syntax, but this explanation has helped me to understand what is doing what and (hopefully) will allow me to adapt this if I need to edit large numbers of text files in the future. 

Thank you again!